# Como abrir o BarcodeScanner em um espaço limitado?

Tags: apache-cordova

Bom dia.

Alguém saberia me dizer como eu poderia abrir o `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner` em um espaço limitado, como uma `<div class="scanner"></div>`, por exemplo?

Já consegui executar e colocar pra funcionar. O único problema é limitar, pois o plugin leva a tela inteira. Procurei na [documentação do plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner), mas não encontrei nada do gênero.

Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Já tentou limitar o tamanho da div pelo css?

Comment: Olá, Victor! Eu faço a chamada na barra de navegação do app e/ou no menu. Gostaria de carregar a câmera dentro da div.